# Detecting a "Drag" from WPF ListView and delegate it to its ViewModel

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to do this in a simple way?
Detecting that something is dragged from a ListView and then tell the ViewModel that something is dragged and tell it which item.

Note: I don't mind a simple solution that doesn't strictly follow MVVM if the "correct" way is too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) contains a Drag-and-Drop implementation that I'm pretty sure would compile in straight WPF without much trouble.  These are behaviors and attributes you can add to your view in XAML and then you just have to handle the modifications to the `ObservableCollection` that your `ItemsControl` is bound to.  Pure MVVM.

If you want a simpler starting point than doing surgery on the Silverlight Toolkit, you can use the same inspiration that the author of the Silverlight Toolkit drag-and-drop support used, Bea Stollnitz's article:

- [How can I drag and drop items between data bound ItemsControls?](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=53)

And here's yet another implementation, that is more Blend-oriented:

- [ItemsControl Drag Drop Behavior for WPF](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/DragDropBehavior)

Don't be scared off if you don't have Blend; you can still use the MVVM-friendly behaviors with just the free [Expression Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75e13d71-7c53-4382-9592-6c07c6a00207).